# ServiceStack RequestBindingException

Tags: c#, api, servicestack

I'm building a fairly simple service using ServiceStack but I'm getting this non-descript error (in the browser when trying to view the uri) on several of my services. errorCode: RequestBindingException. Message: unable to bind request.

Here's the DTOs I have:

```
[Route("/jtip/cases/{Count}, GET")]
public class AgencyCaseSummary : IReturn<AgencyCaseSummaryResponse>
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

public class CaseSummary
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AgencyCaseNumber { get; set; }
    public string AgencyRepName { get; set; }
    public string Service { get; set; }
    public string Milestone { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public class AgencyCaseSummaryResponse
{
    public List<CaseSummary> CaseSummary { get; set; }
    public int ActiveCaseCount { get; set; }
    public int OpenRequestCount { get; set; }
}
```

And here's my service:

```
public class AgencyCaseSummaryService : ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Service
{
    // Injection handled by Funq 
    public IRequestService RequestService { get; set; }
    public ILog Log { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the case summary for the most recent cases
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public AgencyCaseSummaryResponse Get(AgencyCaseSummary request)
    {
        AgencyCaseSummaryResponse summary = new AgencyCaseSummaryResponse();
        Log.Info("Created new agency case summary call");
        try
        {
            if (request.Count > 0)
            {
                var caseSummary = RequestService.GetRecentCases(request.Count);
                summary.ActiveCaseCount = caseSummary.ActiveCaseCount;
                summary.OpenRequestCount = caseSummary.OpenRequestCount;

                if (caseSummary.Cases.Count > 0)
                    summary.CaseSummary = DTOMapper.Map(caseSummary.Cases);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Api.AgencyCaseService", ex);
        }
        return summary;
    }
}
```

Am I missing anything here? What does the error mean?

Comment: What browser are you using, and does it have the same error in multiple browsers?

Comment: I'm using Chrome and tried IE10 as well. Also, I'm using a REST client GUI tool which has a browser and shows the raw output. The error is the same in all 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[Route("/jtip/cases/{Count}, GET")]
public class AgencyCaseSummary : IReturn<AgencyCaseSummaryResponse>
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

The route attribute needs the URL template and the methods as seperate parameters (see [RouteAttribute.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/ServiceHost/RouteAttribute.cs#L39))

So to fix your problem change the attribute to

```
[Route("/jtip/cases/{Count}", "GET")]
```

As to what the error means, it is throw by the RestHandler ([RestHandler.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.Endpoints/RestHandler.cs#L147)) when the route has been matched but the URL cannot be converted (or deserialized)

Comment: Baffled by a misplaced quote character. Thank you, Will Smith.